# Local Video Screenshot during Netflix

Tags: malware, macos, video

I was just binge watching Netflix from my MacBook Pro on a TV streamed using HDMI. It automatically started the final episode of the season but about 20 seconds into it, a screenshot from a local video file on my computer appeared on my screen for about 3 seconds, after which the Netflix show continued. The screenshot was from a personal video on my local machine that I haven't opened in a month and wasn't opened at the time.

Not sure how to explain what happened. Tried rewinding the Netflix video but did not see the screenshot again. Has my machine been compromised in some way?

Comment: How about inspecting what's going on under the hood.... https://8thlight.com/blog/colin-jones/2015/11/06/dtrace-even-better-than-strace-for-osx.html

Comment: Noticing this behavior in android too, it seems to depend on the codec on my side. Allthough it doesn't show video files on my phone, it does often show a background app where the videoplayer is supposed to be.

Comment: Did you take the screenshot? Was the screenshot an automated frame grab for an icon? ... if either of these are the source of the screenshot, then it's probably accidental and/or erroneous upnp control ....

Comment: Nope, never took a screenshot nor is it the icon for the video. If it helps, the frame grab had colors similar to the frames of the Netflix video playing.

Comment: The error is reproducible. When I reload the page and start the video from the beginning, the frame pops up at the same time. What’s the best way to debug?

Comment: It sounds like a simple bug, not a compromised system.

Answer (score 3):

Vanishingly unlikely that this is an indication of some kind of compromise.  (The only contrived way I could imagine something like this would be very strange copying of your file through the memory netflix tried to read, but so many parts of that don't even make sense).

**It'll be a weird bug (i.e. unintended outcome of software, with no malice involved).**

You mentioned this is from some app that streams it from your mac - was the other video the last thing that app had open?  Was it the last thing you used this was on your TV, in a way where the tv might've cached it? .. I'd bet it could be some kind of caching / attempt bysoftware to pre-load the last thing you watched into ram; speculation, but the chances of 'hacking' being the reason for this specifically is vanishingly close to zero.